# VPN with NAT on a single nic

Tags: windows, vpn

Setup:
Windows 2k8 VPS
1 public ip
1 NIC

What I'd like to configure:
VPN server witch you can connect to and use the VPS's internet connection.
The vpn clients should be given IP's by a DHCP server and NAT should route their traffic over the public IP of the VPS.

I have found the routing and remote access feature in W2K8 R2 but they require 2 NICs. How do I configure them with just 1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you have a look at [openVPN](http://openvpn.net/). I use it on my Linux VPS, but they also have a windows version. It only uses one NIC.

Comment: I've tried to configure openvpn on my linux vps and I think I was going the right direction, but I couldn't find W7 x64 drivers for the client. I know openvpn can deploy on a vmware esxi server (wich the win 2k8 is running on btw) but it would use up too much resources for what it does. I'd rather use the windows solution.

Comment: Normally you do not need additional drivers for the client :/ ?

Comment: I would agree with Lucas here. Open vpn would be Tue way.

Comment: Ok so I'm trying it out ... but i tried to work with the .deb on their site instead of just apt-get install openvpn ... and I see there is a big difference. Anyway ... Thanks for the tip ... I hope I get it working :D